# I've a linear layout in a fragment. How to dynamically add a view to it from the activity?

Tags: android

I'm posting data from one fragment and updating the other fragment by adding a view to it. I'm not using listView. I am using LinearLayout.

I've a very simple doubt. How do I get the view and update it by adding another view to it?

Basically I want to inflate the linearlayout that already has the data and add a view to it in the main activity that adds the fragment.

Edit:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.commentFragmentLayout);
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) ll.getParent();
            View customView = view;



            TextView   commentContext  = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.commentText);

            commentContext.setText("hello");


            view.addView(customView);
```

I tried to do that in the main activity but my view gave null pointer exception.

Edit 2:

```
   FragmentManager fm       = getSupportFragmentManager();
                // You can find Fragments just like you would with a View by using FragmentManager.
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentCommentContent); 
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_list_item, null);


            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.commentFragmentLayout);
            TextView    newText  = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.commentText);
            newText.setText("Important text");
            ll.addView(newText);
```

I tried that and got : The specified child already has a parent. Call removeView() on child's parent first. The problem is, if I call remove view, I lose the previous data that I've inserted in the layout.

Comment: use getViewById to get the desired view. and then you can add your other view to it.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't make any sense. You get the parent of the `LinearLayout` with the id `R.id.commentFragment` from the fragment, in that parent you search for a `TextView` to set some text and then you add the parent to itself.

> I've a very simple doubt. How do I get the view and update it by
>   adding another view to it?

You get the `View` of a fragment with `getView()`. You search for the desired component on the view returned by `getView()` and then add the desired view to that container:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.commentFragmentLayout);
TextView newText = new TextView(context);
newText.setText("Important text");
ll.addView(newText);
```

> Basically I want to inflate the linearlayout that already has the data
>   and add a view to it in the main activity that adds the fragment.

You inflate a layout file not a view that is already present. I really don't understand what you want here try to explain better.

Comment: You can't add the TextView from that layout as it already added to a view hierarchy. Instead add the inflated layout `child`: `ll.addView(child);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 LayoutParams params =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 lay=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Lay);
 lay.addView(yourView);
```